# How to set sign keystore in unity cloud build?

Tags: android, apk, unity-game-engine, keystore, google-play-games

i set the package name, version code and bundle version code correctly. Set the keystore and stored it in my unity project.

i committed and push it in git repository(Unity cloud is link with my repository). In unity cloud it is built successfully. We know that committed code in git is automatically build in unity cloud. And downloaded that apk.

[image]

When I try to upload an apk that build from unity cloud to google play console, I am getting

this error

[image]

It works fine and success in uploading apk when I build apk directly from unity editor.

I think Unity cloud build is not linking to sign keystore file.

Please suggest me how to link keystore in unity cloud build.

Comment: Did you get this to work? What did you use for app signing in the Google Play Console?

Comment: i tried it for downloading apk from unity cloud build that apk failed to upload. Instead from unity cloud build, i used to genereate app signing key from  unity editor and create apk then uploaded in the google play console.